# Log4J 2 Async Logger - Message Order

Tags: java, logging, log4j, log4j2

I'm trying to set up log4j2 to log all the messages using async loggers.

```
-DLog4jContextSelector=org.apache.logging.log4j.core.async.AsyncLoggerContextSelector
```

My logger class have this code:

```
 for (int i = 0; i < 100000; i++) {
        log.info("check async " + i);
        log.error("check async " + i);
        log.warn("check async " + i);
  }
```

I expected the messages to be printed to log in order, But actually logging date is correct and order not. Some of file output is:

```
[02-07-20 14:34:25.948] ERROR Log4J2AsyncLogger  - check async 5495
[02-07-20 14:34:25.948] WARN  Log4J2AsyncLogger  - check async 5495
[02-07-20 14:34:58.037] INFO  Log4J2AsyncLogger  - check async 98242
[02-07-20 14:34:25.948] INFO  Log4J2AsyncLogger  - check async 5496
[02-07-20 14:34:58.039] ERROR Log4J2AsyncLogger  - check async 98242
[02-07-20 14:34:25.948] ERROR Log4J2AsyncLogger  - check async 5496
[02-07-20 14:34:58.046] WARN  Log4J2AsyncLogger  - check async 98242
[02-07-20 14:34:25.948] WARN  Log4J2AsyncLogger  - check async 5496
[02-07-20 14:34:58.046] INFO  Log4J2AsyncLogger  - check async 98243
[02-07-20 14:34:25.948] INFO  Log4J2AsyncLogger  - check async 5497
[02-07-20 14:34:58.047] ERROR Log4J2AsyncLogger  - check async 98243
```

Is there a way to print the message in the order? Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The messages are displayed in the order after upgrade log4j2 version from 2.1.9 to 2.13.3, The [message order bug](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/LOG4J2-2031) was fixed in version 2.10.0